# Next.js create-next-app won't work anymore

Tags: next.js, yarnpkg, npx

I have been able to get around and make Next.js apps a lot as of late. However, something changed and I cannot seem to find a solution to my issue. I run `npx create-next-app <app name>` and it hits me with an error and only creates the `package.json`. It then shows me this error. Any insight would be appreciated.

```
>npx create-next-app imageuploads3
Creating a new Next.js app in /Users/Jeremy!@#$%^%$#/Desktop/Code For Learning/imageuploads3.

Using yarn.

Installing dependencies:
- react
- react-dom
- next

node:events:505
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn yarn ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn yarn',
  path: 'yarn',
  spawnargs: [
    'add',
    '--exact',
    '--cwd',
    '/Users/jeremy!@#$^%$#/Desktop/Code For Learning/imageuploads3',
    'react',
    'react-dom',
    'next'
  ]
}
```

Node.js v17.8.0

IIOS 12.3

`npx create-react-app` works just fine BTW.

Comment: Did you update Node.js recently?

Comment: I did. I thought that may have been the problem. But I had the issue before I updated Node.

Comment: I started having problems a few months ago with Next.js, and it happened when I updated Node. So i decided to use the minimum Node version and it started to work fine with me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because Yarn isn't enabled. You have two options:

1. If you want to use NPM instead of Yarn, pass the `--use-npm` flag in:

```
$ npx create-next-app --use-npm myapp
```

2. For Yarn, [enable Corepack first](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install):

```
$ corepack enable
$ npx create-next-app myapp
```